# Jquery Accordion to slide back in on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xhtml

Hi guys what i have done is an accordion drop down which drops down on click the header of the DIV used in my coding...... everything works fine but the thing is i want the drop down to go back in if the user opens one and clicks on the same .... i am new with J QUERY ... but i have tried implementing a logic but it doesn't seem to work at all i would be happy if i could know what i am doing wrong or any help possible in the J QUERY to do what i am trying to do

MY XHTML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>TEST</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

<div class="container">

    <h2 class="acc_trigger"><a href="javascript: void(0);">ONE</a></h2>
    <div class="acc_container">
        <div class="block">
            <h3>CONTENT 1</h3>
            </div>
    </div>

        <h2 class="acc_trigger"><a href="javascript: void(0);">TWO</a></h2>
    <div class="acc_container">
        <div class="block">
            <h3>CONTENT 2</h3>
            </div>
    </div>

    <h2 class="acc_trigger"><a href="javascript: void(0);">THREE</a></h2>
    <div class="acc_container">
        <div class="block">
            <h3>CONTENT 3</h3>
            </div>
    </div>

    <h2 class="acc_trigger"><a href="javascript: void(0); ">FOUR</a></h2>
    <div class="acc_container">
        <div class="block">
            <h3>CONTENT 4</h3>
            </div>
    </div>

</div>

    </body>
</html>
```

MY CSS

```
html {
    overflow-Y: scroll;
}
body {
    font: 10px normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1.7em;
}
*, * focus {
    outline: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
h1 {
    font: 4em normal Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 20px 0;
    color: #aaa;
}
h1 span { color: #666; }
h1 small{
    font: 0.3em normal Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.5em;
    display: block;
    color: #666;
}
h2.acc_trigger {
    padding: 0; margin: 0 0 5px 0;
    background-image: url('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlh9AFcAPf/AFZWVh0dHWqy5E99kWu05Wmv41xcXFRUVDZmuiw2OmOp4WdnZ3W42W+25hITFHjA6ni+6jFIfDVit2Kr4lOO0IPP8Xa96T5FVYLN8HzJ7jBMjWOq4S5OljdGajxASVZ7ixoaGj09PRodHjw8PBUaHEdHRzs7OyMnKUZGRjo6Ojk5OUlJSTg4ODc3NzY2NjU1NVJSUnR0dDQ0NDMzM1BQUDIyMnJycm5ubnNzc2xsbG1tbWpqamlpaXV1dXFxcXBwcIHQ8X/O74PU84LS8W9vb1mg3YXW81ad233L72Gq4V6n4IfY9Gav41yj3my35mmz5HvI7lWa2mtra3nG7YjZ9VOY2TExMV5eXmCk3l2k3iMjI1paWmVlZWhoaGOs4my25Q4ODiAgIDhquzZZl3S25T9KXIDO702HzbLk91ab2p3h9zNIeDxVfGyx42Wd2Y3d9liQ0EJzsk2J0XCo3o/Z9Xuu4UeCzZLB6Wit4aLf9jRLgVWZ2kBHT0Z/y8/Pz16l3mux4zFIdzRKdGFhYTBasj9yv3O76KDi+Kjj90FupkBBQ4DK7j5hk4fP716X12mn3K3Y8rzq+YjT8WCh2zlosytQpVqa10FhjEd7xWqu4kl8xXCw4ZfV8pDZ9D9OXJTd9ZPe9jZhrTtioEFcfWat4czMzK3m+UFml5PX81me2zU9TT9eisft+kBwv3C551CK0oPM72aq4WNjY4PS8WKd10J/zG+x4z1ET4/b9qPP7mqw4TY7RFhYWFNTU1mc24rP73G15XvG7TFcsm245jJMgWBgYEBikUBjkmy05YeHh8XFxaSkpJOTk3O96bu7u19fX4DF7Vqh3cLCwmycsr6+vp6ennrH7YTJ7GRkZHi+32imv3vD7HvH61+Wsk5lb2OIlygrLC9IUYTP8V+m32ew42615k13i3auzYjF4GGo4HC35yAsMj1WYWiw5IbK8E5OTkVFRU1NTT4+Pk9PT1FRUUtLS0pKSkhISD8/P0NDQ0RERExMTEFBQUJCQkBAQP///yH5BAEAAP8ALAAAAAD0AVwAAAj/AP/980PEHryD8PQpzMewYb5+EPs5bKhQH8KDKDKW2Hiv470VIFfYG2mvnsmTJvepXMmypcuXMGPKnEmzps2bOHPq3MmzZ0uUQIOeJEm0qNGQSJOC9Mi0accS9zZKnUo1o9WrVy9qRVixa9eJYBlGHEuWn9mzaM36W8uWLb63cOPik0e3rl15IfLq3RvC3xVpAv8to8FFx43Dh3Uo1pGjMePGkB3nUHzDMGLERH5k/vHDhw8bn22IHo2jtOnSMVKrTt1jterWrmOzlj2btu3YPWC/vh1DN27ern0D3z1cOG3jrWEbD/67d+3lt6HLPh3jtPXTNnCM3s49e/fv2z2L//883rMNzj7Qq+fMXjOR9+7fy39/ub79+4srL94fGfLjxlLkIMWABA64w4E7SIHgggwyyMODEEK4Q4QUQtjFAleUwMxA9NwAwD71kBSSUyQ2FRJJKK0Uz4rvtPjOPDDSICMN9NRoIz0w5Kjjjjz26OOPQAYp5JBEFmnkkUgmqeSSTMKA441QRmnjjFRWaSWMWGap5TwudumliyuGKeaYNQkFlFFHKZVUiUxR5SZWWG2llVd06hNWQxDlMw8XJShzgywAjLSUR1PBCedUTIGE4kkqsthillbSKOWklFZq6aWYZqrpppx26umnoIIa6agzbmlqli9+qWqXY7YaJk5mov+EZppqIsXmU24WamhWcnJV51d3PkRWRGe9s8UV83Sxjz2D4lrCrrtKlahII6W4j5guYhlpqNx26+234IYrLriklnvquVyuqq6rrt4U61CzilirrbdGletG0PLaa0K/LhSssMNCdFY+xfSjDw/MrkAovvrKiZW0HSlabUoqhZmttlaOq/HGHHfsMcflhozuluqWzK6Y17r7rknxCjovvSXeK1W+DW/Vb0XBBjxWWoOYoE8Xzc5s1ZwVaXUVxB9RWxLF2D4aY8YfRy311FR/TGPIV9IwMsklf3kymSqv3HLCLytcr8zP0ozCvgfd7O+dOgucVjEm5IMNw77a6ZDOExX/jREKSJ+4NEsWf7n14YgnrvjijDfu+OOQR6541+t+fTKsK7M8trxlN3sr2gznyza/N/8LcNxppd7W6mu9dUUK/ciSdt54xj0WRQohpBFHSVPLaMWFdyn58MQXb/zxyCePKuWVW94uTZkHtTnZL39Ur72gqz2622+HZbvcqZ/FOutvGQD7IBn5ujf44UfkUO5/Qyw4xcDHY7jy+Oev//78M848q867HPRAFD3Nja1znjubzNS2tu25LWen01n41DK+tsTFfPx4Rtv0Jiy0+IMPo0hEHGpRizgkYhR88Ada8sQQ+MFjdx6R2NLq0aim/e+GOMyhDnfIwx768IdAZF4A/7+GuQKGaHou69z1FpY97bGNexzMme0mKL4KukUuWNyCCvhxBX7VTnyeOMUr6pALSLCCFZDIRR1ecQpPqNAsLMwH/HYHld5NjIb1C14Q98jHPvrxj4AE4hCfFzYjIjGJ1Vsi9ppIMwc+0HQR3BkVKWjF1mExLvLghQr8YQCcdVAtl5DDHSJhCjWA4g1vAIUaTBGJO8jhEm/kBwu9Er86Jo0ovyPcIHfJy1768pfADKYwh0lMnxCwgIdEpBKXCDqhOXF0pINinSD5vUnyo5JXvORb6AKATW7BX+BTxDHcgIZD4IIK6EwnOnFxCDS44RiKOMssu/JCGNrxji4hpj73yf/Pfvrzn8FMWU+MCK/pIRBmCmxm2hoJzWhK0yvUnOIksWlJbc6FmyrABy/E0g8K4sMYc0DEJ5ZA0pKalKSfQMQcjIGPtcBRIi30Gx0jJsOgGPOmOM2pTnfK056+hKBnOmIyqXdQRSp0oc984kNLZ7rvddSa18SmRe9CVbr0ggX4AMAnr4mPVTgiD3QwgljHSlay0iEPjlhFS+UJU3rWU341BYpP50rXutr1rjoBqqyEesiDIvR62UOq6KC51H5BkqOosyZF/THVqtZFLzDAqlbltpYy2IETnRCCZjfL2c4KoROcsEMZXCrLttLTKrwT3AxzidfWuva1sM2rXmU1VGX/IlCRi1wgAxtaWMMe1qmKpahFL+pYuuSFBiyQxwGeaklGbAIVsxiCdKdL3eoOYRao2AQj3kJaWeJujoCzpWoXNdvymve86E2vetfLXqHUlih+/SszjypYaDX0Ir1l6r+AG9xKDnebxcULX/gyDxaEgB6WpMst+vALSQDhwRCOsIQhLIlf9OEWdOHuG+dZy2kZpb0gDrGIR0ziEC/tvUT1K26dpVAGpu++G+Teb6sJ1cUON8DGHfCAR8DjHvt4BO9owYETLA82WKIRZgiCkpUMhHBoY8lQXrIZGmEJNmS4pRs2bS3FqzTylvjLYA6zmEFcLRSnuKgrpm997QtjKM6Y/8b9teJ/AexYHfPlx3gegQn20YIR0ADAeREFKWCBhEIbGggicAA7GGDoRhcaFqQQRV6uTFoO1zO80xqvmTfN6U57+tOgDrVB46uUFbdJzYBzcQPbLOPDRnJYUPWgf+eMY7wI2M55ybOPTcDrXvO6Hn2eB6BDQIkGLAIKyE62OEQQABKQwBzcSLa0F9EASkxaHhp+aUz/hukYIkXU4A63uMdNbjNTi9TyTbOa17wrGDv0kfvlb6xt/N9a5xjXut61r30NbCAPWwyGCMYUBk7wCgRAC2EIgAPW0Q1rEHzgwTCEGK6d7dJu+9K8o6mmy83xjnv84+9VFLoTaOp1hy6phP+Vpqud+tR5S7Xetca1XvLN433bfAUuMEE9cq1nEyDAFcNwgtCHvo2DawHhCehGA4Yu9GG4AgG85jHFsaxtOYKXjhk3tda3zvWue/3rYA+71k1+L1W/2N0xdrOrESvvOM+a1jiW+V5oXnOb2zwFeM+73lOggr77XQUocMEI7MFzPYdCF194guIX/wCjg+Mbv3hA4hf/hC/oIhQm6PHUK21ai1w6vEgTu+hHT/rSm/70uSW7M1WNdqKpfe0sjzUlXw73AMt95jS3+933znu+/73v8BD8CgpvgjFMggBMSL7yLXACLXgDHe6wADLIofzkE2ASY8i81EOA7Wy7z+qePxr/olBP/vKb//ylh4rqdWX2obnb8ypf+6sDJvuoCnfOxC3u7Qufb937uvd793t/F3wjAA9513csIAhnIABJ0IAO2ACecA7RJwBe4IAWKABnIAgs0Hd5p3160X1UV3Xg5zetV4ImeIIomIIquIIsKCf5BVHytz4sVxYut1jZdGP2dm/4Rnc95n+9BoC8J4C/xwJEWIRGaIQtkIRKuIRJ6AJO+IRP6A85lw++R4QtsAsIQIFKsIVb2A4PYAECsAFcOIZK4AUCgAC70AJEyIEpEHUjMHUhWFow9T4vWId2eId4mId6uIdLFYNSNIOwVn9VZIP4Bxc5eGu3x4N154O8BoQB/yiEf3eEkliETFiJTQiFmPiEL7CJL4APL2AC/YB3CMgCLUAMFFAAWdAEqtgE47AB6ZCKqxiLWVAAFEAMariBKtCBHsh9INhd30eHfBiMwjiMxFiMdeiHYAGIgSiIs0d7+HeIjyV3iriIjOiIegeJQziJR2iJlZiJ3siJmygPn0iFVUiKqiABeKAARbCO7NiO7lgECoAHEqAKt8iGvfaGcMh5cfRdxtiP/viPAPmCyOg9yihJzGh/91eI2JaD3JeI08iI/2eNvoeNo6iNlMiNS+iN3wiOI/ACKcAPfHeRLhAIhQAIf3AEKJmSKqmSfwAIhRAILpCERZiLeOeG+Ehp3f8lh784kDzZkz75k0AZlELZVAWZWAeJkDbIWIVoiIe4f7iniBDZiBLJdxOJjRa5jRiZkRqpieDYleAoAzJgAmHpD+WohC4QAZjQBliQBlHQlm75lmmABW2ACREQkzKJizXphh8IF2yxQmQxlIAZmII5mITph0VJf0c5iEm5lIaYfzHnlCHwkFFpAlNZlRR5lReZlZe4lU7olV4JlmCZAmGJD6KoAlaohi0QAa1gC7GQClXwmrD5mqkQC7bQChGwhGtIk22ofTfZizk5LIUZnMI5nMQ5kBJxmMsoiCqUlBbEmI75mE4pmVE5lRQZiZh5mprJmVDomZ8JmiogAykgDxX/qYRruAaEAAfAkAlY4At7sAe+gAWZAAxwQAhrEJJ2OZO6qZfX5ps5+VLI+Z8AGqACOqAEWqD81XJHyZyr01LOSWdNCZmRKZ0QWZmlWZ0ViZmauZnayZ3dCZoeCposAJ7iOZ5qmAJ9cQF6IAyaQAuPQAZk8Ai0oAnCoAcXwA/yYAJWiJ80aZP7yZd9mToGGqRCOqREWqRFKUuJKWsKylhKyZjQaBcQOo161nMTKpEWmo3XmaEaqpEc2qEf+qEtMAMmOpFHmItvKA8e0AEawAGVUAkcoAEd4AHGRZkqcIu4mJ+7yIv8GUtsZaR++qeAGqiHCUdJqpjM2aDPyZDRGaFQ/zmd1GmZl3mdpKil2tmZXcqJX5qpMuACM5B5FWqRQliOp6mjuqh5Paph/amTgrqqrNqqf1qoSKmgiJqocYeIMiel1OiDFAqpVpmlWtoClXqpX6mpHzoDLyCmI0Cm2GmXLbCJ32iW5JmbeMqbH1gXccE6sJqt2rqt3Nqt3pqgS9qcs8qUTwqh/CehjmqlV+p3kvqrwFqpLiCsw0qsMjAD9nqv+GqsnUqZyjqp7wqvzEqqukitp4qqbfGtCJuwCruwDJsW4bqg40qr0AmZuEqlk0mh63qhGOqu8Cqvm0ivYJmvIjsD9cqvn4qdW4qJTCiweUmwegqCWLY6DTuzNFuzNv87QQ9rQU06q0+qg4sqpZP5gxi7rpLqrxkKsB77sSA7siNbAxVqmigLsE6Im9I6rT5WrdaKRTm7tVzbtV77tWAbtjsbsQ5arub6lLgatEI7tERbtBwrtUkLsvVar0yLrzVwt3ibtwZYlZmZspm4slU7sC77sjBrsGJ7uIibuIq7uBBLtj17F2c7d2lrsRNqstTZtm77tsEat3JbtyKbt6DbAgtwgOzat2b5hJZohH8nuFeLtYVruIwbu7I7u7Q7PmRLro8buYxasWpLmZZrjbmIue2quZsrr3JLt557r6ALur1QCiFAuhr7q2Xqd6xrqvt5ZXJRu9q7vdx7uLdbtmb/G7kVm6vpyrbVWbQom51Iy7lLm7zKu7x4OwPU8A/V8LRI6K53GbjVu32ui73f+78AHMACPMACvJCPS1W6i7Zp27tSuatPe6Xom77q27HGe7wh674zAL8abAUczMHJEBilwAX4YJ33m5WSuLqCy5v42L+vS8Au/MIwHMPfe8B1lsDnCrQM7MAPDMERTLwbyr6di8EavMFW8AL04AyBMRAFgV/dUzv7+F1GM1PeJkOrZS2xdcVYnMVabBN6VVtoBlipV3Yo54L6FW8SNVEVBHP6J3N+ARgCMRiFUR/8IRn9IRmUYRn1kRmb0Rnk8R3XgRqysRzSwRzHMRy8kRuEbBvS/zHIzWHIxAEcjFwbq5EcklzIhKwclVwcjkwdf3wd3gEe26EdoPwd5UEe5XEenbEe6dEenDEf8TEf9HEfsmwf+bEfc9wf/yEgAlIgBLIgCtIgwIwgFSIhw0whF5IhG+IHHfIhQjUipqZaVqxHGCMjUtIk1nzN2JzN2rzN3LzNT8IpWHMliHNDQ1QmYnNAZQNYaDNY+9JqcCMRe9InfxIoCXNqJxctoRdX9BM8kAI1VfPPAB3QAq0p4Vwli5MqOFTOhWQmo5bOn7PODNXO8EaQiMkPxoIsylLPTGR2+aw01mJD00wlAz3SJF3SVVPQBn3QOaTQ5vwum3NbCZUru6VUvv/1hxVNMAaDMEFzz2zzMBmnzzV0MU9TJSZd1EZ91KGC0uI8zjrkPALV0i7dMl9MIowU0WRcxhMBZ2bRMz+z00jlep6nO6j10x7NNPw81CKN1Gq91mx9I1ej1POgNZOT0AFURFEdLzD90GJs1Vdd0xRd0WdBN3aDNzGW1QHTNy4kxfdEP9fiKF7SP5Ad2ZI92cTDQ79k13f90lPNJs00xmD9K0R5xjg7a68TO7NT2GxnO1C8ZRqHT3l0P5Qd27I927HtQ5cNPUDV0NVjNnoN0ezcK6/31xKExrNmPv2APqvWPcRCRTuZ2KDX2oMT1I9N29Rd3dadPCsNTGVyTNGj24n/NF97/dvAPdFZPX8GqTrOiEEa5EUc5UEgJEIkZEIoxKdx5NxkTV41pEeBtN/83d/+/d9CFFALnTnJtNm9rVt8bTPubNOAHT4JaVFaxEXsvVX+EEZjVEZnlEZr1EaxVN/h99yLvc9jAuAkXuImfuI/pN2Y3d19tUzgXdVsJtHk/c4N7uAPfkmZtEmdBE4t5w+hNEqldEqptEqt9Eod3nngdd/43RIA1eRO/uRQHuUszRMENVTxZVQtNtMpd4yhPdxURG+N1U3+8E16E07jVE7npE7pxE7uBE9sFVNFM9bQPUP5JOV2fud4nue89NQ70cVIRGpYnuUJPt5cbsZePtrO/4jjGKVR7R1VHxVSI3VSkp5SKxWCHp7kqaXPrLXFnN7pnj5Q5VUSIQfoL+7bnq3geBhRov3liY5JtXZVWUXhXfVVYVVWti5WZ5VWa1V1biXF0CxXnx7swj7sMGFeom7lpB7oZcducMJbqf5mh47ob4dFcZcXkRXrlOUPloVZntXtmwVaosV5cJ47cn5PVYxHxJ7u6q7F6IVi6IZbgj7oqH6HK6fVNt7qrm57IYBcysVcSulc0GVdAj9d2KVdFedd495hc+5lY9bwDv/wEO9e5vbuJUdfLoZ2fKjqRsnq065N1Y5rBTZkSqlgDOZgE3byEVZhF4aTvP7hWUfFdxTxMv8/8zTfXic26hQP7xZ/8e8X3Axe4/fe8XIxsTuYb0Em8gBmZEgWZUzf9FNWZSxvcVbH2jT1YTV/9Vif9SzOV8ie88re2Tx/Xz5P46su7Wlce1XlkLnHZ342bIJGaI7GAAMw93Q/AIzWaJAmabxYcZZW7hoH8yAX+II/+II/culW6p3N7M3e8zP+88lZY0Kv6LZnqzpGd7rXb8J2UXlRbMcmbRnAAA4ABqIv+iSQDdIGBdRmbXtv6VqGcbbUO4BP+LI/+7S/aedm+F5ncqzHavFn6BvvdmePg0S/Y5Z/+X32Dv8WcA83BdaAAR8AAtAP/R8AC8sfcRO3+uI+9a6fabH/X/ve//3gD18igftdR3a7L/a93+W/T9xypsb6fqu554M4p3M8x2s/F3RM5wTNcA0JABBhBCa41szJwYPDXCEwYWLEiBAh5MnDh8+fP378+vXLl0/fR3jwUIxEUcKkyXspVa5k2dLlS5gxZc6kWdPmTZw5de482dPnT6AlSA4lSjTkUaRJlX5k2tTpx45RpU6NutHqVaz9Mm7l2vXiV7BhK44lW3biWbRnI65l2/bhW7hvG86lSzfFXbx5U6jg21cFChcj7EWUG0rXlyeJFRN4MC1AmADTHhBQnPiLrlAOH0acWPFixo0dmYYc6nPnadSpVa9m3VpnUNixi842qtT2/+2nuaFS5V01a9auwbmGJf617PGxaZXLa9t8bVzodaU31Fv9rt++8AKvIPzQxJhJBJiMJ88EGTRPYdhBQ1Z+PIFJYzRDlDj2s1XRIEWSNO3a/38AAxQQtRLuie3Ak2hTcKjbGtQnJN2e6m3C334T7sLiikMOueXScs456KKbzi7r8sLOL+1GgAcvvlgQ5AwBkpBxxiQmcOWcExgoZwIaZRTgDEFY4AsvzdaiyDOMQOMov6YadPJJKKOUckoqq7TySiyzhDJCLp2a8MuOKhTTqguDy/BMfzY0q8PlPmQrRDhHJLFEE0/0iwU889RTzxb69PPPPl0QdNBB/XHBhHz2Uv8BzxZ2QUAAL5SQdFIlJjDkHEMUoFRSLwRAYJcW8BwyhYY2k+hIi5LUKLSpunT1VVhjlXVWWmu19VZccwNzV9/GHLNMYNEkTk0O2fTQTbfgjEvOuujUy07s9pQ2T0CrDZRQbAd9YdsX8HnBhH6uW5SFFoihoIAsmlB33SwUYEKBdNdtIosCKCAmVCFVILLIU+1TFb9WcxV4YIILNvjgXHkF09dfgS1TWLCIPc7YDpHtTlm4mJ3TWUWh7Wtaaa2tNluSud1Wnm8TVZRRVSTAQ4EiYpa5iGhqnjlmBfCQQBV8R52Lvn6RVJJVqRA2+mikk1ZaN4V3ZVhMhx+G+CKJzcL/h2K1mLMY42U1notjcT1uEWQ+Rf6T5JJNHuGFFPjZi9oWXAikEED+OOJuvPPO+w9ACgnEhT7z1PeuUk3tLFVVV72qacYbd/xxyCOXfHLKeXv68qilnjriqtfEeiKLk+XaO69NAPu6jj0me0+zAUWbUJNjj10GGUyo3Z+VyQ00AkzawCKNKIIXfvg0sGgDkwgADzxfwgs30t/Es6p8euqrt/567Ke63NfMg93cuM7JouhztUJ/bvQRSqfudLHvXJ3R1v18HXbZZ6ddhhRqx0dc+MmNoBVbxCIVVSBgAQmYiljYohUR+JOoBkeq+XAGVV/hivSyd0EMZlCD1uPI9hrW/72tYOR7nAtfRchXPvOFAH3pUx/72je29+kufvOjX/1Mdj8ZqAB/8oChn0S1BkLAARiZwIIv9rAHX2AhE8CAAyHW8DblCe6BzpPgBCnYFQ9mUYtb5GIXvfhFMHoRNCAUzgjFkqYSJueEoEvhxUanPtOdLmwvjCH8ZkhDQdlQdjjk4/1YsMOP9S8FIfDHBfQgDE3Q4hFkIMMjaKEJYejhAvyQhwkYJcXBFY4+Z4Fe4rYSRlCGUpSjJGUpsaIRMmLIjFRDYxrXiJY2qnCFDmkh2F4YrTrGT3401OMe+9jHFsxgkB3bk74gIg8PdEADHKhEJTiggQ54AHSmUwG+8jVFfv+dyoqfwaIpvflNcIaTlGNMpZlW2UpXvpKN5oPIClnoNTnq65YwfJ8ur8XLXnLrl790wQwcEjay2Sl3/XMgNt9ipMMhzpOKE2dDHfpQiF6lnF45J9XSqMY1SiSF7iQdPOWYuvbl0p5xw2c+t7XPPs7gBcIcATHtqLwWbKtk8vNhQfcVwSqiSqHcnGhPffpToAZVqEOdaEXBd9GJqTOWbpwlHONoy3nSk2wjJSkeTXpDlNJuBlvlaldV6s84BlKGeCRUTa+Zl5+ZSptkKQ5R3fpWuMZVrkA16lGRakJ1ai2WHH1nLV04zzra0Z5kvepJsyoDryZ2Boh9qktleE+SAQr/k2jVJEITulOezlWzm+VsZ3taV1beVXxKXWo7mwrHj4JUbIGlKlldUFjDZlWxiq3BHOEGWTw2sKDYnA/Q0oIc0AZXuMMlbnGN+z3Rbiiv61yqLPnq1PV9NKrjEulgXfvawh4WsYidbVdr8F3whndFqbstbiOr22vyFqc51SmSjvte+MZXvvNFZ3KXi8LmOneWfYVnY6F6y8AKVpeuhe0LtMvd7no3vOFtwQJYJNbH7lJQ1tKTX27aW7agBbj05XCHPfzhYSV3tMvNr345Cl1SSVe10ApwhO9I2OxqN8FeXfCCe1GKEDxYqiMtZl8uDJcMa/g4ICZykY08XBGPOK8lkzbxaVGb2hXbqcWtJTBsDzxjBdf4uzOgxj+qYdvy8hiTD4SgJoHG3vYmWc1rZnOb3fxmYo3vvrBkcpOd7FQo6xiwU6YyjE164PtheataJrQVDG3oZPxD0aXgAj7cV7bWScvCF8ZwkIUMZ0xnWtOb3vSclVNnproTutFN7XSlGsM+W9XKgBb0DAhdaCu8gB7OUHRAAAA7');
    height: 46px;   line-height: 46px;
    width: 500px;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: normal;
    float: left;
}
h2.acc_trigger a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 0 0 50px;
}
h2.acc_trigger a:hover {
    color: #ccc;
}
h2.active {background-position: left bottom;}
.acc_container {
    margin: 0 0 5px; padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 500px;
    clear: both;
    background: #f0f0f0;
    border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px; 
}
.acc_container .block {
    padding: 20px;
}
.acc_container .block p {
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 5px 0;
}
.acc_container h3 {
    font: 2.5em normal Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    padding: 0 0 5px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ccc;
}
.acc_container img {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 15px 15px 0;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #ddd;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

MY JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//Set default open/close settings
$('.acc_container').hide(); //Hide/close all containers



//On Click
$('.acc_trigger').click(function(){
    if( $(this).next().is(':hidden') ) { //If immediate next container is closed...
        $('.acc_trigger').removeClass('active').next().slideUp(); //Remove all .acc_trigger classes and slide up the immediate next container
        $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown();
                //Add .acc_trigger class to clicked trigger and slide down the immediate next container
    }
    return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
});
 $(function() {
    $( '.acc_trigger' ).click(function(){
      collapsible: true; //TRYING TO CLOSE IF CLICKED AGAIN I KNOW AM TOTALLY WRONG IN THIS CODE 
    });
});

});
```

This is what I have done so far ... all I want is after the div is shown on click , if the user clicks the same header then it should slide back in ..... any idea of how to do it? Thanks in advance ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to add an else part

```
    else{
        $('.acc_trigger').removeClass('active').next().slideUp();
    }
```

[Check on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UWF5q/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Simple code which i wrote. This works good, just some CSS work to do..

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<style>
    ul{list-style:none;}
    p{border:1px solid;}
</style>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#tab > p").hide();

        $("#tab h1").click(function(){
            $("#tab >p ").slideUp(0);
            //$(this).siblings("p").slideDown();            
            $(this).parent().children("p").slideDown(0);
        });

    });
</script>

<style>
    h1{
        float:left;
    }

    p{
        width:35%;
    }
</style>
    <div id="tab">
        <h1> Hello </h1>
        <p> Hello PAra Hello PAraHello PAraHello PAraHello PAraHello PAraHello PAraHello PAraHello PAraHello PAraHello PAraHello  </p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab">
        <h1> Hello 1</h1>
        <p> Hello PAra Hello PAraHello PAraHello PAraHello PAraHello PAraHello PAraHello PAraHello PAraHello PAraHello PAraHello</p>
    </div>
```